# Python parse blob object

Tags: javascript, python, video, webrtc, webm

What I gonna do is to capture a user video from webcamera in HTML than send this video to python which is to do the emotion analyzing.

I have get the video in by others work (RTC) which is a blob in javascript. My problem is how could I receive the video properly?

I try to use websocket to send the blob and the problem is how could i parse the received data back to a video in python?

I try to find some stuff but nothing. Maybe I choose the wrong idea. It would be great thanks if anyone give some tips.

Comment: How do you transfer the video to blob?  You can parse the data in the opposite way.

Comment: No, I just use getuserdata in HTML to capture the video and it would store in blob